# Deliver Html file using Vue.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, vue.js

i am using Vue.js as frontend and express.js as Backend.
When i start the express.js server with npm start, i would like to deliver the frontend component from Vue.

I am using Vue generator & Express generator, when i deliver the index.html file with

```
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

the browser shows an empyt site, because there is only written.

```
    <div id="app"></div>
```

I think i have to build the index.html file first, because the frontend part is divided up in different Vue components (.vue files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your express server has to serve not only the index.html file but also all the other built js files. If you are using `vue-cli`, you have to serve all the files that you find in the `dist` folder after you run `npm run build` (production mode build).